How to configure a virtual DHCP server on an ESXi 7.0 system using pfSense and a physical switch?
Currently, I have a setup where I'm trying to extend the DHCP service provided by pfSense to affect physical devices outside the virtual environment. This includes devices like laptops/PCs connected through a physical switch as shown in the diagram:
                               xxxxxxx                                  
                             xx      xxx                                
                            x INTERNET x                                
                            xx        xx                                
                             xxxxxxxxx                  ┌──────┐        
                                  │             ┌───────┼ PC1  │        
                                  │             │       │      │        
                                  │       ┌─────┴───┐   └──────┘        
                     ┌────────────┼───────┤PHY SWITCH   ┌──────┐        
                 ┌───┼──┐      ┌──┼──┐    └─────┬───┘   │ PC2  │        
                 │vusb1 │      │ETH  │          └───────┼      │        
                 └───┬──┘      └──┬──┘                  └──────┘        
  ┌──────────────────┼────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┐   
  │ ┌────────────────┼────┐       │                                 │   
  │ │OUTSIDE switch (vswitch)     │                                 │   
  │ └────┬────────────────┘       │                                 │   
  │      │ ┌──────────────────────┼─┐                               │   
  │      │ │ vSwitch0               │                               │   
  │      │ └───┬────────────────────┘                               │   
  │      │     │ ┌──────────────────────────────────┐               │   
  │      │     │ │  pfSense LAN (vSwitch)           │               │   
  │      │     │ └─┬───────────┬──────────┬─────────┘               │   
  │ ┌────┼─────┼───┼───────────┼──────────┼────────────────┐        │   
  │ │    │     │   │           │          │                │     <ESXi> 
  │ │  ┌─┼─┐┌──┴┐┌─┼─┐         │          │                │        │   
  │ │  │OPT││WAN││LAN│         │          │                │        │   
  │ │┌─────────────────┐       │          │                │        │   
  │ ││                 │       │          │                │        │   
  │ ││                 │    ┌──┴────┐  ┌──┴────┐           │        │   
  │ ││    pfsense      │    │  VM1  │  │  VM2  │         <VMs>      │   
  │ ││                 │    │       │  │       │           │        │   
  │ ││                 │    └───────┘  └───────┘           │        │   
  │ │└─────────────────┘                                   │        │   
  │ │                                                      │        │   
  │ │                                                      │        │   
  │ └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘        │   
  │                                                                 │   
  └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘   

I am using two network/NIC ports: one linked to my ESXi server via PCI and the other through a USB Ethernet dongle. The former connects for general internet access, managing ESXi, and acting as the gateway for pfSense's DHCP service. The latter, is intended for DHCP to the physical switch. Initially, I attempted connecting the USB Ethernet dongle to the LAN switch on ESXi, but faced roadblocks of nothing working. I then created a separate port called ”outside” and connected to ”outside” switch, configuring it as an additional interface (opt1) on the pfSense VM in hopes that DHCP would work with such approach.
I stumbled upon a forum thread discussing a similar setup, but it seemed discussions just…vanished or stop to make any further traction.
Overall, all VMs connected to my LAN network request DHCP with no problems, but anything connected with the USB interface are not as lucky. Is the issue related to my interface setup arrangements above? Should I consider configuring a VLAN for the physical interface? If this is solely a pfSense issue, how can I direct the OPT interface to interact with the DHCP server established on my LAN network?

Note: The physical switch being used is an unmanaged switch.

Have you tried passing through the USB device directly to pfSense instead? ESXi being the enterprise thing it is, I don't expect it to be good at USB NICs.

@grawity_u1686 is that different than adding the USB to pfSense? I currently have the USB Ethernet dongle as OPT in pfsense. Are you saying to make the usb interface the LAN instead and see what happens?

No. I mean bypassing the ESXi vSwitch and having pfSense see the USB interface as an actual USB interface instead of an ESXi virtual interface.

I ended up reassigning the management port and that solved all the issues that I was having. Changing the management port of ESXi from the internal NIC to the USB Ethernet dongle allowed pfSense's DHCP server to be requested from both virtual and physical clients. This is the new setup:
                             xxxxxxx                                  
                             xx      xxx                                
                            x INTERNET x                                
                            xx        xx                                
                             xxxxxxxxx                  ┌──────┐        
                                  │             ┌───────┼ PC1  │        
                                  │             │       │      │        
                                  │       ┌─────┴───┐   └──────┘        
                     ┌────────────┼───────┤PHY SWITCH   ┌──────┐        
                 ┌───┼──┐      ┌──┼──┐    └─────┬───┘   │ PC2  │        
                 │ ETH  │      │vusb1│          └───────┼      │        
                 └───┬──┘      └──┬──┘                  └──────┘        
  ┌──────────────────┼────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┐   
  │ ┌────────────────┼────┐       │                                 │   
  │ │OUTSIDE switch (vswitch)     │                                 │   
  │ └────┬────────────────┘       │                                 │   
  │      │ ┌──────────────────────┼─┐                               │   
  │      │ │ vSwitch0               │                               │   
  │      │ └───┬────────────────────┘                               │   
  │      │     │ ┌──────────────────────────────────┐               │   
  │      │     │ │  pfSense LAN (vSwitch)           │               │   
  │      │     │ └─┬───────────┬──────────┬─────────┘               │   
  │ ┌────┼─────┼───┼───────────┼──────────┼────────────────┐        │   
  │ │    │     │   │           │          │                │     <ESXi> 
  │ │  ┌─┼─┐┌──┴┐┌─┼─┐         │          │                │        │   
  │ │  │OPT││WAN││LAN│         │          │                │        │   
  │ │┌─────────────────┐       │          │                │        │   
  │ ││                 │       │          │                │        │   
  │ ││                 │    ┌──┴────┐  ┌──┴────┐           │        │   
  │ ││    pfsense      │    │  VM1  │  │  VM2  │         <VMs>      │   
  │ ││                 │    │       │  │       │           │        │   
  │ ││                 │    └───────┘  └───────┘           │        │   
  │ │└─────────────────┘                                   │        │   
  │ │                                                      │        │   
  │ │                                                      │        │   
  │ └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘        │   
  │                                                                 │   
  └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘   

